# Flagged a duplicate answer as such, flag was declined - define "duplicate"

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, plagiarism, duplicate-answers

I flagged the second answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4451959/post-form-and-get-file-result-using-jquery-asp-mvc) as "duplicate of another answer", because its content is obviously copied from the answer posted 13 days before it. However that flag was declined because "a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it".

Hence I'd like to know what the criteria for "duplicate" answers are. Must they be **exact** duplicates, as in entirely a clone of another answer (i.e. `answer1.Equals(answer2) == true`? If not, how close in content must they be to be considered duplicate? Finally, if I used the incorrect flag in this circumstance, what would the correct one be?

Comment: Duplicate answers?  Is this even a feature?  Or did you mean plagiarism?

Comment: I agree, that looks like plagarized content, especially given the time diff. Could you provide the actual text of the flag? Was it *just* "duplicate of another answer"?

Comment: I was halfway through an answer saying that the flag reason could better describe the problem, and you definitely could come up with a better flag reason, but honestly on reflection what you have simply should be good enough for the mod to have found this problem and addressed it.

Comment: I'm afraid that's only nitpicking, not plagiarism. The second answer uses `FilePathResult` instead of `ActionResult`, which can be considered as (*slightly*) better semantically. Also, the time diff is 13 days, what's the problem?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi It really does look like the user copied another user's answer and then just made a few minor modifications to it.  That's okay, but requires citation as it is a derivative work.  Without the citation it's plagiarism.  Given the *exact* same file/variable names it seems pretty unlikely that he just independently created identical code.

Comment: By the way, I posted a feature suggestion aimed to reduce the amount of duplicate answers: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270027/encourage-deleting-ones-own-answer-in-favor-of-another-one-in-order-to-reduce-t

Answer (score 35):

I was the moderator who processed the flag. I don't really recall my thinking since the flag was processed in September 2014, but I'll guess that I looked at both answers felt they were different enough to not delete.

However, I've reviewed it again today and I've deleted the second answer.

Typically when flagging something as a duplicate answer, it is preferable that you include a link to the duplicated content.  For example, you could have said in the flag that "this answer was posted 2 weeks later and it basically the same answer as the other one (link)".  Your exact flag was "duplicate of another answer", that really could mean any answer on the question or even another question. The more details you provide to us the better when it comes to this type of flag.

Comment: Should I feel bad that I *automatically* decline all flags that simply say "duplicate [of another] answer" with zero context? Asking honestly. My reason for straight-up declining them is because the user needs to state clearly which answer is being duplicated so I can determine whether or not they are right - without this information, I can't know for the reasons you state in your answer.

Comment: @BoltClock I tend to do the same thing.  If the user flagging can't provide context for what is duplicated I'm not going to guess. I also decline _this belongs on another site.._ with no mention of which site. We aren't mind-readers and we've got far too much to deal with to hunt down where an answer is duplicated from or what site a post "might" fit on.  I did take a cursory glance at this answer posted, and felt it was different enough when I declined the flag in **September**.

Comment: By the way, I posted a feature suggestion aimed to reduce the number of duplicate answers: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270027/encourage-deleting-ones-own-answer-in-favor-of-another-one-in-order-to-reduce-t