# Should I raise a flag for late answers which are just a copy of the accepted answer?

Tags: discussion, flags, not-an-answer, duplicate-answers, plagiarism

I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33164771/3145341) in the review. The user just copied and pasted the accepted answer which was posted on Aug 24 '13. Should I raise a *Not an Answer* flag?

Comment: Note, however, that the answer in this case actually *is* slightly different. It seems that the user is saying that the order of the lines can be switched, and it will still work. Not sure how valuable that is to know, but there you go.

Comment: In the past, I guess it would be deleted if flagged with custom reason, but I'm not sure anymore.

Comment: I've found that if you flag such answers as NAA, robo-reviewers will almost always reject that flag because technically, it *is* a valid answer (in the same way that, technically, I'm an ape). Rather raise a mod flag - these are less likely to be declined.

Comment: Apparently, just changing the wording makes it a different answer. I've had a request declined on this, and my [meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281186/flag-declined-on-late-duplicate-answer) on it downvoted (and automatically deleted). Given the strict interpretation of the "not an answer" flag, it looks like the moderators do not care about cleaning up useless or nonsense answers other than spam, and I gave up flagging for that reason.

Comment: @IanKemp That has nothing to do with robo-reviewing. It is an answer, so a NAA flag is **invalid**.

Comment: @corsair992, I posted a feature suggestion aimed to reduce the number of duplicate answers: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270027/encourage-deleting-ones-own-answer-in-favor-of-another-one-in-order-to-reduce-t

Answer (score 50, accepted):

**Should you raise a flag?**

Yes, the answer should be flagged.

**Which type of flag should be raised?**

You may raise *"in need of moderator intervention"* flag with relevant details.

As [bluefeet♦](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/426671/) stated in [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288369/):

> Typically when flagging something as a duplicate answer, it is preferable that you include a link to the duplicated content. For example, you could have said in the flag that "this answer was posted 2 weeks later and it basically the same answer as the other one (link)". Your exact flag was "duplicate of another answer", that really could mean any answer on the question or even another question. The more details you provide to us the better when it comes to this type of flag.

**Is *"Not an Answer"* flag appropriate for such cases?**

No, this flag type is not appropriate. Even though it could be a plagiarized post however it is still an answer because the OP actually made an attempt to answer the question, which is why *Not an Answer* flag is not valid. Secondly, posts with this flag go into the *"Low Quality Posts"* review queue. Reviewers don't see other answers while reviewing, so they may not know that it has been copy/pasted. Most likely they will vote the answer as *"Looks OK"* and it will not get deleted. [Brad Larson♦](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/19679/) mentioned the following in his [comments below](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308160/should-i-raise-a-flag-for-late-answers-which-are-just-a-copy-of-the-accepted-ans#comment259239_308175):

> The problem with flagging plagiarized answers as "not an answer" is that reviewers in the Low Quality Posts review queue won't have the context to know that it was plagiarized from somewhere else, even the same question. I've almost never seen such posts be deleted in review, and if reviewers all vote "Looks OK" on those posts, a moderator will never see them.

Comment: I posted a feature suggestion aimed to reduce the number of duplicate answers: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270027/encourage-deleting-ones-own-answer-in-favor-of-another-one-in-order-to-reduce-t

Answer (score 13):

Personally, in these cases I would raise a "In need of Moderator Attention" flag with something like this description:

> Duplicate answer. This exact answer was posted by another user <time> before here: <link to other answer>

Comment: I posted a feature suggestion aimed to reduce the number of duplicate answers: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270027/encourage-deleting-ones-own-answer-in-favor-of-another-one-in-order-to-reduce-t

Answer (score 3):

I actually think you should. The entire platform is based on peoples unique answers. If people are just copying other peoples answers then they should be flagged.

Comment: How would you flag it then? It is already explained why NAA is not appropriate

Comment: The only thing would be to send them to a moderator to check. It is called plagiarism and should be reported if people are just copying answers to build up their own rep points.

Comment: By the way, I posted a feature suggestion aimed to reduce the number of duplicate answers: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270027/encourage-deleting-ones-own-answer-in-favor-of-another-one-in-order-to-reduce-t

Answer (score -23):

[According to this authoritative source](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265553/70345), **you should not raise an NAA-flag**:

> Any post that attempts to answer the question, however badly is still an answer. You can downvote such posts to signal that the answer is a bad answer, but it is still an answer.

Personally I think that's BS, but apparently leaving copypasta alone is more important than ensuring quality content. It's almost like the mods *want* more mod flags to be raised so they can do more unnecessary work.

Comment: The problem with flagging plagiarized answers as "not an answer" is that reviewers in the Low Quality Posts review queue won't have the context to know that it was plagiarized from somewhere else, even the same question. I've almost never seen such posts be deleted in review, and if reviewers all vote "Looks OK" on those posts, a moderator will never see them. In fact, I've seen plagiarized posts from the same question actually get voted up higher than the original post due to reviewers in the queues voting them up. The plagiarist probably copied a good answer, after all.