# What to do about pointless* answers?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, low-quality-posts

*By pointless I mean that the answer does nothing to improve upon the accepted answer.

I came across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/10183312) in the Low Quality queue and it basically says the same thing as the accepted answer with less detail. The accepted answer was written 8 months ago so I voted to delete it as I think of it as clutter. But then I looked back and saw two other users voted to keep it open which got me to thinking.

Should answers that contribute nothing new be kept open or are they considered clutter?

Comment: If they explain things in a different way, I can see it having some value. I've had times where a late answer (which covers basically the same things as the accepted answer, just using slightly different wording) ends up being the explanation I need to finally understand something.

Comment: Pointless answers for me fall in the category bad answers. Since they're still answers, a thumb down is the way to go.

Comment: @resueman While that's *possible* it's pretty rare to see answers that do this.  It's pretty common for the late additions to be notably *less* clear.  But naturally, each post should be evaluated on its own merits; you can feel a post is useful even if it's just a re-wording of content in other answers, but you can also feel that a post *isn't* useful because it isn't presenting that same content better.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you feel that a post isn't useful then you should downvote it.  The express purpose of downvotes is to indicate that you feel that the post isn't useful.

You should not be voting to delete an answer just because it's not useful.

Answer (score 3):

We don't have to do anything with them. Better answers naturally rise to the top of the page as they're upvoted, so other answers aren't really getting in the way like they would if they were all mixed together.

Answer (score 3):

If it's a true duplicate answer posted significantly later, you should follow the advice of [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/308178/4320665) and flag for moderator attention.  But for answers that merely "[do] nothing to improve upon the accepted answer" a downvote is more appropriate.  Since it doesn't add any new information or insight to the existing answers, it is by definition unhelpful and worthy of a downvote.

In this specific case, it doesn't really seem like there is any illegitimate stuff going on, but it also doesn't add any new information.  I would downvote the answer and comment (or upvote the existing comment).