# Should we add a "Clutter" flag?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, flags, declined-flags

I came across the question [Redirect using AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11907961/redirect-using-angularjs/29687011#29687011) some time ago.  It is a fairly popular question with a score of 78.  For posterity, the question is asking for help creating a redirect using the AngularJS library.  The question explictiy states that the code `window.location = "#/route";` works, but they are specifically looking for a solution using the `path()` function.

There is an answer on that question with a score of -3 whose entirety is:

> just use `window.location = "your_url"`

I flagged this as not an answer, because it does not answer the question, which explicitly includes this line as code as technically working but not desired.  This flag was rejected because "flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer".  Which I understand.

I then raised a flag seeking moderator attention, and explained that this answer does nothing other than waste users' time.  People who are reading it have likely already read the original question and learned of the `window.location` functionality.  The answer has a score of -3 and provides almost negative value to the question itself.  But the flag was declined for the same reason.

This is my exact flag text:

> I already raised a "not an answer" flag that was declined, but I still feel this is detrimental to this answer. The Question contains this line of code and explicitly states that it works, but he wants a different solution. The code in this answer does work, and does solve the general problem, but I don't believe it's an answer to the question. I think people reading this answer will have wasted their time since the code is in the question.

My hope for a "Clutter" flag would be to remove answers like this that truly add no value to the knowledge gain provided by a particular question, and perhaps contribute negatively to the sites reputation (no one likes seeing negative scores).

Or at the very least, a discussion about what flag would be appropriate in this situation, or why I'm wrong, would be helpful as well.

Comment: Would be good if you wanted to put your original flag text into your post... I've looked at it and I can see given the wording the reason for a declining - given the previous flag and you're just able to downvote :)

Comment: Why not just downvote it?

Comment: "*no one likes seeing negative scores*" - Not true. I like to see them when they should be there.

Comment: I did downvote it.  But it is still there. And I understand that sometimes an answer with a negative score provides value, but in this case there is nothing in the answer that the question didn't already state.

Comment: @dckuehn then it's still an answer - the community is capable of voting and deleting such answers themselves - a mod didn't need to get involved to delete it.

Comment: @JonClements did my flag text come off as hostile?

Comment: You shouldn't be using flags to point out wrong answers; you should be downvoting wrong answers.  You can use flags for answers which are very much *not* attempting to answer the question.

Comment: Related [How can I get a "not even a partial answer to the actual question" deleted?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/319617)

Comment: @Braiam I didn't know that answers with a negative enough score were deleted, so thanks for that link.  Perhaps that solves my problem, given time.

Comment: It's not an automatic process; it's a process in which someone with the privilege to delete answers has to come by and operate on.

Comment: And there's [another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28217261/603977) there that also appears to propose the same solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your NAA flag was declined because it *is an answer* - maybe it's terrible, maybe it's already been mentioned in the question (and you do admit it answers the question etc...), etc... Just downvote, and when you have the necessary privileges - vote to delete if you feel strongly enough about it.

Your other flag of:

> I already raised a "not an answer" flag that was declined, but I still feel this is detrimental to this answer. The Question contains this line of code and explicitly states that it works, but he wants a different solution. The code in this answer does work, and does solve the general problem, but I don't believe it's an answer to the question. I think people reading this answer will have wasted their time since the code is in the question.

And no - your flag wasn't interpreted as "hostile" so don't worry about that - it's a detailed "other" flag - it'd be nice to see more of them - however even you admit in that message that it's an answer (albeit not a great or useful one). It's not down to diamond moderators to evaluate content for anything that isn't causing active harm to the site that the community itself can't handle.

Don't be discouraged - I think you're doing a great job and despite this meta post - I hope you keep doing so!

Comment: I did admit that it solved the problem, but I don't think it answered "the question" because the question itself discussed the line of code as not the answer they're looking for.  It seems I'm being overly pedantic and I guess people who gloss over the full question for an answer might still see value if they find the answer at the bottom.
Thanks for your kind words.  I'm just glad I didn't go sub 1000 after this.  I only just got to 1000 a few days ago.

Comment: Multiple other moderators have said that a months-late _answer_ which merely exactly repeats the same solution as another answer should be flagged: [Robert](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/171222/), [Chris](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274826/), [BoltClock](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302088/ok-to-leave-months-late-duplicate-answers-lying-around#comment231446_302088) and [bluefeet](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288369/). What's the difference between that and the information originally being in the question?

Comment: @JoshCaswell When you read the mod message *[...]The code in this answer does work, and does solve the general problem[...]* - leads to the fact you don't need a mod for that - that's what downvotes/community deletion is for. I like to think there's a certain amount of good faith and lee-way given - perhaps the poster of the answer didn't read the question properly and was making a good-will effort to help.

Comment: @JoshCaswell the other posts you link are more what to do about people trying to gain something from answering (and poorly) from other older answers - in which case it's generally fine to delete them if they add nothing useful or are blatantly trying to game the system.

Comment: Interestingly, this one was not well received initially and [was on its way to deletion](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/7718321) until code formatting was added, by a user who at the same time left a comment critical of the repeated information.